# Primes in the intersection of arithmetic progressions

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

> Let $a,b,r,s$ be given constants. We know that that the arithmetic progressions
> $\{ax + r : x \in \Bbb Z\}$ and $\{by + s : y \in \Bbb Z\}$
> intersect if and only if $\gcd(a, b) \mid (s − r)$.

In this case, I am asking if this intersection contain at least one prime number. I know about the Dirichlet theorem, but I am not able to apply it here.

Comment: The intersection is $m\mathbb{Z}+t$ where $t$ is an integer congruent to $r$ mod $a$, $s$ mod $b$, and $m$ is the lcm of $a,b$. What’s your obstacle to applying Dirichlet?

Comment: @Mindlack: Can you convert this into an answer.

Comment: The question "before" this is [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2109477/prove-that-the-arithmetic-progressions-intersect-if-and-only-if-gcda-b-mid).

Comment: $4\mathbb Z$ and $6\mathbb Z$ intersect, but the intersection does not contain primes.